# Pods are not getting created and not running after a long time also

Tags: docker, kubernetes

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-0                   0/1     Pending                      0          9h
cd-jenkins-7fb5d96d69-v9svc   1/1     Running                      0          9h
hello-1571555340-872pt        0/1     Completed                    0          2m17s
hello-1571555400-5wzrk        0/1     Completed                    0          77s
hello-1571555460-spjm6        0/1     Completed                    0          16s
webpod                        0/2     ContainerCreating            0          10h
wordpress-557bfb4d8b-bcbs7    0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          9h
```

I want to know the exact reason ,why these pods are not running.
Tried executing kubectl describe pods .But not finding the exact reason .
I tried deleting other pods forcefully,but that's also not working.
Please help me in running  these pods.

Comment: What kind of cluster and worker nodes are you using?

Comment: Is there anything in the `kubectl describe pod` error that looks like an error message, or an explanation as to why the pods wouldn't be getting scheduled?  Do you have any of your own source code or deployment artifacts to help others reproduce this problem?

Comment: Please share:  

1. Yaml files that were used to create those pods (cassandra-0, wordpress-557bfb4d8b-bcbs7,webpod) 
2. Pods description using `kubectl describe pods [POD_NAME]`
3. Node resources information using `kubectl describe [NODE_NAME]`
4. Your setup and environment (kudeadm, minikube or cloud)

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
Kubectl get pods -o wide
```

It will tell you the node where it is running, then check

```
Kubectl get nodes
```

to make sure that your VMs are ready, if any of them is not ready then turn it on

Pods takes up pending state when they don't get adequate resources (CPU/MEMORY) to get scheduled

And if you have only 1 VM then you need to resize it to high memory and CPU

Comment: I am executing these command on Google Cloud Shell . How to start the VM explicitly.    - apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webpod
  labels:
    app: webpod
spec:
  containers:name: webapp
    image: training/webapp
  - name: ubuntu
    image: kumagaur/ubuntu_customnew
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: nginx-proxy-config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      subPath: nginx.conf
  volumes:
  - name: nginx-proxy-config
    configMap:
      name: mc3-nginx-conf